# What is the process for proposing a "wiki lock" on a question?

Tags: support

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/297415) on another SE site (actually a comment to it) mentions a "wiki lock" which can be applied in certain cases to specific questions.

An example of [a question fitting this format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229854/gis-or-remote-sensing-in-the-movies/229855#229855) was supplied from the GIS site.

There may be occasional questions here on SO for which this would be appropriate, but what's the procedure to propose it? Would I just flag it and explain the reasoning to the moderator in the flag comments?

Also, is "wiki lock" the correct terminology?

Comment: I'd simply call it "lock". Locks are applied by diamond moderators, but only in very rare cases. If you encounter a question which warrents it, flag it for moderator attention and explain why you think it should be applied.

Comment: Alternatively, if it's a high-view question, you can open a discussion on meta to discuss if such a lock is warranted. There are very few on-topic questions on SO that warrant such a lock, it's mainly reserved for historical ones.

Comment: Wiki Lock is what we've always called it. I don't love how ambiguous that sounds to someone unfamiliar with our system, though, but there are just a limited number of words that are useful to describe it.

Comment: To answer your direct question, make your proposal based on the audience you want to evaluate the post.  If you want a determination solely from a moderator, cast a custom moderator flag and explain in detail why the post merits a wiki lock.  If you want a broader audience, propose it on the site's meta.

Answer (score 15):

It's implemented *as* a lock, but it's more like an *archetype*. It's a slightly different structure that a question / answer pair could take.

Traditionally, questions can have multiple answers. Sometimes, good questions can have *many* answers. Allowing only a single community-wiki answer forces one larger, coherent and complete answer rather than 4 to 5 pages of fragments one would have to put together on their own (which resembles traditional forums, something we try very hard not to be).

It is applied by mods or staff when a question is really useful, but falls into the [good subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) category rather than outright *objective* category (where there's naturally only a few possible technically-correct answers). This puts all of the useful bits from *all* of the answers into one coherent place that's maintainable by a larger subset of users, and avoids a lot of duplicate information.

As [Erik von Asmuth wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379368/what-is-the-process-for-proposing-a-wiki-lock-on-a-question/379370?noredirect=1#comment665141_379370), it doesn't really *lock* stuff like a traditional lock would, it just limits the question to having only one answer, and requires that answer to have wiki status.

Creating a post *with this archetype in mind* should probably be avoided unless there was prior collaboration on the associated meta site that involved the moderators. This is more something **we use when something shows a need for it**, not really something we like to start off with, but the idea of that isn't *totally* off the table.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I actually thought it might be the right 'archetype' for some older existing questions, rather than any new ones.

Comment: So for an existing question with 'n' existing answers, what would the process be if such a wiki archetype were to be applied? First edit the n answers into one good one, for instance?

Comment: @DaveInCaz do said question shows a clear need for it? It's an on topic question at all? Are all answers equally good by their own, or only the collection of answers is what has value? Has there been a continuous support for such question in the way of incremental improvements?